# Searching terms in list, and replacing them with corresponding terms in seperate list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I am trying to find and replace some terms. I have 3 seperate files. The first file, we can call 'berries' and is the .txt file that includes terms we shall search for. The second file, 'newberries' is the .txt file that once a match is found, should replace the found match with the 'newberries'.  The file in which we will be parsing and replacing will be 'berrylist.txt'. For the first two files the positions for the term to search for and term to replace it with are the exact same. So line 2 can be replaced with line 2 of the 'newberries' file and so on. I started thinking of building a dictionary and finding and replacing but could not wrap my mind around it.
My second option would be to use regex and search the terms and just append my '_3' between the end of the name and the ' " ' that is is closed in.  So in the file to be parsed it would show as "blackberry" and would need to append to make the term "blackberry_3".

```
find = open('berries.txt')
findline = list(find)
replace = open('newberries.txt')
replaceline = list(replace)
with open('berrylist.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    with open('berrylist.txt', 'w') as f:
        for findline in f:
            data = lines.replace(findline, replaceline)
```

CONFIG FILE EXAMPLE: FILE NAME: td-adc-post.txt
set device-group TESTDEV-ADC pre-rulebase security rules "IA - Auto Pod Control" 
set device-group TESTDEV-ADC pre-rulebase security rules "IA - Auto Pod Control"
set device-group TESTDEV-ADC pre-rulebase security rules RDC_MQ 
set device-group TESTDEV-ADC pre-rulebase security rules RDC_MQ

EXAMPLE SEARCH TERMS: FILE NAME: ADCdup.txt
(on line 9) IA - Auto Pod Control
(on line 50) RDC_MQ
EXAMPLE CHANGE TERM TO: FILE NAME: ADCdupreplace.txt
(on line 9) IA - Auto Pod Control_3
(on line 50) RDC_MQ_3

Comment: Please post example contents for the two first files and the corresponding expected result file.

Comment: Also (unrelated but...) learn to close your files.

Comment: Palo Alto config, search for the rules including the quotes that they are wrapped in, so like "GSLB Flow PROD_BE RDC" is a term to search for in the config and the file with the list of them.  The end result the rule would be changed to "GSLB Flow PROD_BE RDC_3" , The quotes included.  I made a regex to append the _3 but just did it to a seperate file, not actually searching for terms and then appending

Comment: file.write('\n'.join(['"{}_3"'.format(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in lines]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a dictionary and process through each line.

```
with open('berries.txt') as f:
    findline = f.read().split('\n')
with open('newberries.txt') as f:
    replaceline = f.read().split('\n')

replacedict = {}
for i in range(len(findline)):
    replacedict[findline[i]] = replaceline[i]

with open('berrylist.txt', 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.read().split('\n')
with open('berrylist_done.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for i in lines:
        fout.write((replacedict[i] if i in replacedict else i) + '\n')
```

No need to worry about closing files here because when you use `with open...`, it's automatically closed as soon as you quit the `with` block.

Comment: Its returning a syntax error  for line "replacedict = {f: r for f, r in findline, replaceline}" under the second comma

Comment: @YepramYeransian Fixed.

Comment: your code now runs and finishes successfully but for some reason it is not replacing the terms in the berrylist nor anything in the berrylist_done.txt.  Is there something causing this in a file or?

Comment: @YepramYeransian Can you add sample files into your question so that I can test it out?

Comment: updated, let me know if this was enough. Could PM for more detail if it was  not enough. I tried to make it more readable but failed.

Comment: The lines from the config file to not match the lines in the parse file nor replace file. Only those to share the same line numbers. The config file is about 5000 lines long.

Comment: @YepramYeransian I'm still not sure what it is. You should try modifying the code bit-by-bit and see when it fits your requirements.